# Redirect not works in Server but works in Localhost

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel

I use CodeIgniter 3.1 in my project. Everything is running well in localhost, but when I upload to server, all controllers that using redirect didnt work. It only shows blank page. Here my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>
```

Please, help me find this solution. Does CI version is the main problem? or the htaccess itself? This is my first time upload my project to server and I hope I didnt miss something important .. thanks

[EDITED]

I use another server, it works fine. Maybe the problem is in the server.

[EDITED]
Horray... Problem solved. Just put ob_start() at the begining every .php. 
(more information , visit http://kakaeriel.com/mengatasi-cannot-modify-header-information/)
Thanks for everyone who helped me find this solution.

Comment: Check if mod rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper. Do you get an error? "when I upload to cpanel" - btw, cPanel is just the control panel that you use to manage your hosting account, you don't "upload _to_ cPanel". You are perhaps using cPanel's file manager to upload files.

Comment: @Tpojka : mod rewrite is enabled, but still dind't work

Comment: w3dk : thanks for the information, but still didn't work

Comment: Put this in `index.php` file: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`. It will show PHP errors if any.

Comment: @Tpojka:
Here my error message ( I put your code into my controller that contain redirect syntax)
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/...)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 564

Backtrace:

File: ...
Line: 36
Function: redirect

File: ../index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: @Tpojka:  oh.... i got the answers from that errors.... just put <?php ob_start(); ?> at the begining in every file.php.... thanks for your attention...

Answer (score 0):

I assume your host could have same config as Godaddy's. You could try this https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips

Comment: hmmn, and you're sure the controllers are named with the correct case and you redirect accordingly e.g Controller named `PRJ_Students.php` would be redirected to with `redirect("PRJ-Students");`

Answer (score 0):

In `/application/config/config.php` set `$config['base_url']` like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://[hostname]/'; //like www.google.com
```